# User registration keep failing: username, email and password are not saved in the database

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, reactjs, express

I'm trying to create a react website that need authentication and I'm using a mysql database.
My problem is that when I try to register a new user nothing is added in my db, instead I find the email, username and password added in my url bar.
I've also tryied to create an user manually and then do the login and that also doesn't works. I'm not getting any kind of error, the code just keep giving me back empty username, email and password in the console.
This is my code:

```
/controllers/auth.js
import { db } from "../connect.js";
import bcrypt from "bcryptjs";
import jwt from "jsonwebtoken";

export const register = (req, res) => {
  //CHECK USER IF EXISTS

  const q = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ?";

  db.query(q, [req.body.username], (err, data) => {
    if (err) return res.status(500).json(err);
    if (data.length) return res.status(409).json("User already exists!");
    //CREATE A NEW USER
    //Hash the password
    const salt = bcrypt.genSaltSync(10);
    const hashedPassword = bcrypt.hashSync(req.body.password, salt);

    const q =
      "INSERT INTO users (`username`,`email`,`password`) VALUE (?)";

    const values = [
      req.body.username,
      req.body.email,
      hashedPassword,
    ];

    db.query(q, [values], (err, data) => {
      if (err) return res.status(500).json(err);
      return res.status(200).json("User has been created.");
    });
  });
};

export const login = (req, res) => {
  const q = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ?";

  db.query(q, [req.body.username], (err, data) => {
    if (err) return res.status(500).json(err);
    if (data.length === 0) return res.status(404).json("User not found!");

    const checkPassword = bcrypt.compareSync(
      req.body.password,
      data[0].password
    );

    if (!checkPassword)
      return res.status(400).json("Wrong password or username!");

    const token = jwt.sign({ id: data[0].id }, "secretkey");

    const { password, ...others } = data[0];

    res
      .cookie("accessToken", token, {
        httpOnly: true,
      })
      .status(200)
      .json(others);
  });
};

export const logout = (req, res) => {
  res.clearCookie("accessToken",{
    secure:true,
    sameSite:"none"
  }).status(200).json("User has been logged out.")
};
```

/routs/auth.js

```
import express from "express";
import { login,register,logout } from "../controllers/auth.js";

const router = express.Router()

router.post("/register", register)
router.post("/login", login)
router.post("/logout", logout)


export default router
```

pages/Register.jsx

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import "./register.scss";
import axios from "axios"

const Register = () => {
    const [inputs, setInputs] = useState({
        username:"",
        email:"",
        password:"",
    })

    const [err, setErr] = useState(null)


    const handleChange = (e) => {
        setInputs((prev) => ({ ...prev, [e.target.name]: e.target.value }));
      };

    const handleClick = async (e) => {
        e.prevendDefault()
        try {
            await axios.post("http://localhost:8800/api/auth/register", inputs)
        } catch(err) {
            setErr(err.response.data)
        }
    }
    console.log(inputs)

  return (
    <div className='register'>
        <div className="card">
            <div className="left">
                <h1>Title</h1>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisci elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullamco laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur.</p>
                <span>Already have an account?</span>
                <Link to="/login">
                    <button>Login</button>
                </Link>
            </div>
            <div className="right">
                <h1>Register</h1>
                <form>
                    <input type="text" placeholder='Username' name="username" onChange={handleChange} />
                    <input type="email" placeholder='Email' name="email" onChange={handleChange} />
                    <input type="password" placeholder='Password' name="password" onChange={handleChange} />
                    {err && err}
                    <button onClick={handleClick}>Register</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Register;
```

Comment: For JSON, you need to add `body-parser` in express. Have you already done that?

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I have not used body-parser, where and how should I add it?

Comment: https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/body-parser.html

Comment: @PisaPonente I wanna point at your typo of `e.prevendDefault()` should be `e.preventDefault()` inside `handleClick` function.    Next in the latest versions of Express you don't need to install additional `body-parser` as it exists in the Express itself, just call this middleware using `app.use(express.json())` - **Orders matter** so put it above all your routes inside your main *server.js*

Comment: Thank you! I have corrected the typo and now I'm able to see errors in the console:
`Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` and `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'data') at handleClick` , but I have no idea how can I fix them